# read and write LinkedList of Bject

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a beginner in Java.One of the problems i have is to use a arraylist in different classes. 
MainWindow class read a file to arraylist

```
public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList <Product> pl;
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();

boolean test = false;

ObjectOutputStream oos;
ObjectInputStream ois;

private String file ="C://temp//Data.dat";
String number ="";


public MainWindow() {
    initComponents();
    pl = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        do{
            list = (ArrayList<Product>) ois.readObject();
            for(int i =0; i < list.size(); i++){
                pl.add(list.get(i));

            }
            for(Product px : pl){
                number = px.getpNumber();
                System.out.println(px);
                System.out.println(number);

            }
            System.out.println(pl);

            //System.out.println(table);
        }

        while(test = false);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("file not founf");
    } 
    catch (EOFException ex){
        System.out.println("end of file");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        test = true;
    }

    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("class not found");
    }
    finally{
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
public ArrayList<Product> getProduct(){
    return pl;

private void addPanelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   addPanel ap;
     try {
         ap = new addPanel();
         ap.setVisible(true);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

I want to use the same Arraylist pl to add a new Product to the list without overwritting the ArrayList.
I don't know how to do this without loading the same file in every class i need ArryList with the loade content from file

Answer (score 0):

You should import it for each `class` you need it. But, if you are very frequently using the `ArrayList` and only the `ArrayList`, then you can create a `class`, like:

```
public class MySharedArrayList {
    public static ArrayList<> pl;
}
```

and then you can import this small file everywhere, but I believe we are over-thinking it. Do not optimize prematurely. This microscopic problem might never arise, therefore it might be a waste of time to deal with it.